# DataBind() at specific times

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have an eCommerce site that has some special shipping rules.

Basically, the Freight Type of certain products determine whether or not shipping is free or not based on the total cost of everything in the cart.  There are multiple Freight Types (roughly 13 or so), and I need to display these in the Shopping Cart sorted by Freight Type (along with some sort of identifier, like a header).

The current shopping cart is a table that binds data based off of predetermined fields (productImage, itemId, name, etc.). What I need to do is sort all items via their Freight Type and then insert 1 row at the beginning of each Freight Type specifying their Freight Type. My current approach is to check the types of Freight of each item, then add them to a list which I want to later use `DataBind()` on.

The problem is `DataBind()` can't be used more than once without overriding.  Example:

```
//This works
try
{
    base.DataSource = cart.Items;
    base.DataBind();
}

//This doesn't work
if (freightTypeOne.Count != 0) {
   try
   {
       base.DataSource = freightTypeOne; //freightTypeOne is a list of Items
       base.DataBind();
   }
   catch 
   {
       //handle exceptions
   }
}    
if (freightTypeTwo.Count != 0) {
   try
   {
       base.DataSource += freightTypeTwo; //freightTypeTwo is a list of Items
       base.DataBind();
   }
   catch 
   {
       //handle exceptions
   }
}
```

+= can't be used from what I'm seeing and just doing an = overwrites the information. I'm also having trouble inserting a new row in between this bounded data. **I can only insert rows before or after the data.**

So basically, using the above approach, am I able to get this as my final result (or something similar)?

```
if (freightTypeOne.Count != 0) {
   try
   {
       // add new GridViewRow with TD that has: "Freight Type One" spanning full row
       base.DataSource = freightTypeOne;
       base.DataBind();
   }
   catch 
   {
       //handle exceptions
   }
}    
if (freightTypeTwo.Count != 0) {
   try
   {
       // add new GridViewRow with TD that has: "Freight Type Two" spanning full row
       base.DataSource += freightTypeTwo;
       base.DataBind();
   }
   catch 
   {
       //handle exceptions
   }
}
```

This is all done in a DLL if that helps. The data is pulled from the database, and this code is in a CreateChildControls() override. Forgive me but I am rather new to .NET so go easy on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
base.DataSource = freightTypeOne.Union(freightTypeTwo);
base.DataBind();
```

With the above code you don't need to check the counts - it's fine with empty collections.

It's *not* fine with `null` (i.e check your collections are not null prior to the union if you must).

**Assumptions**

The data source variables are of type `List<T>`, e.g.: `List<FreightType>`. I made this assumption since you used the word 'list' in your question (I may be wrong).

Note:
 You'll need the `System.Linq` namespace in your class in case you don't already have it.

Comment: Awesome, that worked for sorting it.  Now I just need to figure out how to add a row before each Freight Type.

Comment: To add a row you have to manipulate the the list before binding it.  You can loop through the items in the list and add them to a new list along with the rows you want to add before each Freight Type.

Comment: @ClintB I'm not sure that's exactly what I am needing to do. The items in the lists are fine, I just need to add a new row to the table before each list. I'm just not sure how to do that and include it in databind()